# Prove that the nonzero element $[a]$ of the ring $ Z /(n)$ has a multiplicative inverse iff $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra

First, if $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then the linear combination is $ax+ny=1$. $Z /(n)$ is the set of equivalence relations of $n$. Now what do I do from here knowing these?

Comment: Reduce the equation you have there modulo n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $a, n$ are coprime. Consider $x, y$ such that $ax+ny = 1$. By homomorphism of $[\cdot]$, we get $[a][x]+[n][y] = [1]$, and since $[n] = [0]$, we have $[a][x] = [1]$, so $[x]$ is a multiplicative inverse of $[a]$.

Conversely, assume there is an inverse $[b]$ of $[a]$. It follows $[1-ab] = [1] - [a][b] = [1] - [1] = [0]$, so $1 - ab = cn$ for some $c \in \mathbb{Z}$, so $ab + cn = 1$, hence $a$ and $n$ are coprime.

Comment: Why did you say $[y]$ = $[0]$ when $[n] = [0]$? And are we assuming $[x]$ is in $Z/n$?

Comment: Whoops, you're right. And $[x]$ is the equivalence class of $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Do we assume $[x]$ is in $Z/nZ$? BTW, what is $Z/nZ$?

Comment: $n\mathbb{Z} = (n)$ is the set of all multiples of $n$. $[x]$ is the set of all $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ that differ from $x$ by a multiple of $n$. $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ as a set is the set of all $[x]$ for any $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, so yes, $[x]$ is contained in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ by definition, no matter which integer $x$ is.

Answer (score 0):

If $gcd(a,n)=1$ then $ax+by=1$ for some $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ by the Euclidean algorithm. This implies $[a]\cdot [x]=[1]$ since $[ny]=[0]$. Hence $[a]$ has a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. The converse direction is clear.

Comment: Are we assuming $[x]$ is in $Z/n$?

Comment: Yes, for $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ we write $[x]$ for the class of $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Wel this question wasn't too bad :).